# LibGDX make player rotate towards mouse pointer (Player facing mouse)

Tags: java, libgdx

I am tryna makin' a 2D game with a 3D player (kinda of Factorium). I got stuck on the rotating of the player. I'd like it look always torwards to the mouse. e.g. If I move mouse on the top-left of the window, player will rotate towards the same direction.

I read on some other question about the method below, but it doesn't work properly:

```
private void rotatePlayerToMouse(OrthographicCamera camera) {

    Vector3 mousePos = camera.unproject(new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
    Vector3 playerPos = this.getPosition();//this.instance.transform.getTranslation(Vector3)

    float degree = (float)Math.atan2(mousePos.y - playerPos.y, mousePos.x - playerPos.x);
    System.out.println(degree);
    this.instance.transform.rotate(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f), degree);
}
```

This method allows player to rotate. Player rotates both direction, but it doesn't stop rotating...

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two obvious problems here:

- You've labelled a variable `degree` that's actually measured in radians, not in degrees.
- You're telling the object how much to rotate *by*, not giving it a target angle it should rotate *to*.

These can both be solved by reading the documentation for the methods you're using. It tends to show when you don't.

```
float radians = (float)Math.atan2(mousePos.y - playerPos.y, mousePos.x - playerPos.x);

this.instance.transform.setFromEulerAnglesRad(0, 0, radians).setTranslation(playerPos);
```

Comment: `setToLookAt` would be even better due to matching intent and fewer calculations.

Comment: I was concerned that `setToLookAt` might point the object's z+ axis at the target (as the corresponding method does in Unity), rather than the x+ axis as it looks like OP is trying to do here. I'd welcome a second answer if I got this wrong though!

Comment: Sure it is working...almost properly: I scaled my model with 32f, 32,f -32f. And when I move mouse, scale has been reset. But doesn't mind. I will scale with BlockBench and not more in runtime. . Anyway `this.instance.setFromEulerAnglesRad` is instead  `this.instance.transform.setFromEulerAnglesRad`. I just had to sub PI/2 to adjust axis. Really thanks for your help

Comment: `I was concerned that setToLookAt might point the object's z+ axis at the target` in fact I had some similar problem when I tried using it